# Notepad++ plugin find end of file and full path?

Tags: plugins, notepad++, scintilla

How do I find the end of the file and the full file path in a scintilla document by writing plugins for notepad++ in c#. I tried the following code:

```
    string nEnd;
    Win32.SendMessage(nppHandle, NppMsg.NPPM_GETFULLCURRENTPATH, 0, out nEnd);
```

but I do not have a SendMessage method which outputs a string value.. 
For the end of file I do not find a NppMsg, is there anyne or how should I manage that?
I want to write automatically at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the way to find the end of the document:

```
    Win32.SendMessage(pCurScintilla, SciMsg.SCI_DOCUMENTEND, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

For full path use **StringBuilder**

```
        StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(Win32.MAX_PATH);
        Win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.nppData._nppHandle, NppMsg.NPPM_GETFULLCURRENTPATH, 0, path);
        MessageBox.Show("path : " + path);
```